# Can I develop a Mobile website using Drupal?

Tags: drupal, mobile

I want to develop a website using Drupal that can be accessed on mobiles. Can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a page on google full of useful links
**An overview of Mobile modules for Drupal**
http://mobiledrupal.com/content/overview-mobile-modules-drupal

Then theres the mobile theme and modules
http://drupal.org/project/mobile_theme
Adds the ability to choose a mobile theme in admin/build/themes/settings which is used for serving users on mobile devices.

http://drupal.org/project/browscap
The Browscap module provides a replacement for PHP's get_browser() function. get_browser() is difficult (or impossible) to configure for most users in shared webhosting situations, and requires attention to keep the underlying data (browscap.ini) up-to-date. This module avoids the configuration issue by storing the data in a database table, and the freshness issue by automatically retrieving the latest data on a weekly basis (if cron.php is run regularly).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, sure. Drupal allows you full control on the HTML generated, so you just need to create a theme that is optimized for mobile users. You may be able to find some themes that already have support for this, you should search.